# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: GPU sync failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia

I have following installed:

- Window 10
- Python 3.8
- Tensorflow-gpu 2.3
- Cuda 10.1
- CudNN 7.6.5
- Nvidia gtx 1080
- Driver Version: 451.48
- Memory:  8192MiB

During the training it gives following error:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "training.py", line 519, in <module>
   history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, \
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
   return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1103, in fit
  callbacks.on_train_batch_end(end_step, logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 440, in on_train_batch_end
  self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 289, in _call_batch_hook
  self._call_batch_end_hook(mode, batch, logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 309, in _call_batch_end_hook
  self._call_batch_hook_helper(hook_name, batch, logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 342, in _call_batch_hook_helper
  hook(batch, logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 961, in on_train_batch_end
   self._batch_update_progbar(batch, logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1016, in _batch_update_progbar
   logs = tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\tf_utils.py", line 537, in to_numpy_or_python_type
  return nest.map_structure(_to_single_numpy_or_python_type, tensors)
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 635, in map_structure
  structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py", line 635, in <listcomp>
  structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\tf_utils.py", line 533, in _to_single_numpy_or_python_type
   x = t.numpy()
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1063, in numpy
  maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
 File "C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1031, in _numpy
  six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
 File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: GPU sync failed
```

InternalError: GPU sync failed

Any leads?

Comment: although you don't mention it, you seem to be on windows.  If a GPU kernel takes longer than about 2 seconds to run, you can hit the CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT.  You may wish to read [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/timeout_detection_recovery.htm).   You will also find many questions on stack overflow that discuss this.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have updated the question, I added more detail

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried setting WDDM TDR Delay to 10 and 30 but still getting the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112126/gpu-sync-failed-while-using-tensorflow

Comment: Surveying [various reports](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS828US828&ei=zE2KX9n8NrKu0PEP58O3-AQ&q=tensorflow+gpu+sync+failed&oq=tensorflow+gpu+sync+failed&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQDFAAWABg1bABaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjZko_NwbrsAhUyFzQIHefhDU8Q4dUDCA0) it seems that the most common reason may be that your GPU is out of memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GPU Sync Failed While using tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112126/gpu-sync-failed-while-using-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the paths for `CUDA` and `CUPTI` are set properly as below for enabling [`GPU support`](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) in your system.

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

Sometimes the `GPU sync failed` error occurs due to high usage of `GPU` by other applications or processing large input data. So you should stop those applications or notebooks and try again executing your code.